# Order by summary in hibernate using criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Let I've the following crtieria query:

```
int offset;
int count;
Date from;
Date to;

//Initialization of offset, count, from, to variables

ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList().
    add(Projections.groupProperty("date"));
addSumProjections(projections);
criteria.setProjection(projections);
criteria.setFirstResult(offset);
criteria.setMaxResults(count);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("date", from));
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("date", to));

private void addSumProjections(ProjectionList projections) {
    projections.add(Projections.sum("clickCount"))
        .add(Projections.sum("funPlayers"))
        .add(Projections.sum("funRounds"))
}
```

I would like to order the resulting table by sum of `funRounds` property, computed by adding of corresponding projection `add(Projections.sum("funPlayers"))`. Is it possible to do that using criteria query?

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898926/using-sum-and-arithmetic-result-as-order-key-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. The question can be marked as duplicated.